# React Hook does not work properly on the first render in gatsby production mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, emotion

I have the following Problem:

I have a `gatsby` website that uses `emotion` for css in js. I use `emotion theming` to implement a dark mode. The dark mode works as expected when I run `gatsby develop`, but does not work if I run it with `gatsby build && gatsby serve`. More specifically the dark mode works only after switching to light and back again.

I have to following top level component which handles the Theme:

```js
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(() => getInitialIsDark())

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      console.log("save is dark " + isDark)
      window.localStorage.setItem("theming:isDark", isDark.toString())
    }
  }, [isDark])

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isDark ? themeDark : themeLight}>
      <ThemedLayout setIsDark={() => setIsDark(!isDark)} isDark={isDark}>{children}</ThemedLayout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

The `getInitalIsDark` function checks a localStorage value, the OS color scheme, and defaults to false. If I run the application, and activate the dark mode the localStorage value is set. If i do now reload the Application the getInitialIsDark method returns true, but the UI Renders the light Theme. Switching back and forth between light and dark works as expected, just the initial load does not work.

If I replace the getInitialIsDark with `true` loading the darkMode works as expected, but the lightMode is broken. The only way I got this to work is to automatically rerender after loading on time using the following code.

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false)
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && isReady) {
      console.log("save is dark " + isDark)
      window.localStorage.setItem("theming:isDark", isDark.toString())
    }
  }, [isDark, isReady])

  useEffect(() => setIsReady(true), [])
  useEffect(() => {
    const useDark = getInitialIsDark()
    console.log("init is dark " + useDark)
    setIsDark(useDark)
  }, [])

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isDark ? themeDark : themeLight}>
      {isReady ? (<ThemedLayout setIsDark={() => setIsDark(!isDark)} isDark={isDark}>{children}</ThemedLayout>) : <div/>}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

But this causes an ugly flicker on page load.

What am I doing wrong with the hook in the first approach, that the initial value is not working as I expect.

Comment: how do you render your Layout Provider. Do you use wrapRootElement or directly add it in each page?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I use the `gatsby-plugin-layout` to wrap all pages into the layout provider.

Comment: `isReady` seems pointless - can you do the same thing by changing the order orf 1st and 3rd useEffect? And console log may contribute to the flickering. Best approach would be to pre-fetch and pass in the value of isDark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to set your initial state like this?

`const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(getInitialIsDark())`

Notice that I am not wrapping getInitialIsDark() in an additional function:

`useState(() => getInitialIsDark())`

You will probably crash your build because `localStorage` is not defined at buildtime. You might need to check if that exists inside `getInitialIsDark`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did test using the getInitialIsDark directly. It does not crash if the localStorage is not defined at buildtime, instead the function defaults to false as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've reread the question and seen that you mentioned that. Sorry, my bad. If `getInitialIsDark` defaults to `false`, could it be that when gatsby builds and can't find localStorage it just returns the value `false` or `undefined`? You could instead call the function `getInitialIsDark` inside the `useEffect` on mount, "updating" the state with the correct value once the component mounts.

Answer (score 2):

@PedroFilipe is correct, `useState(() => getInitialIsDark())` is not the way to invoke the checking function on start-up. The expression `() => getInitialIsDark()` is truthy, so depending on how `<ThemedLayout isDark={isDark}>` uses the prop it might work by accident, but useState will not evaluate the fuction passed in (as far as I know).

When using an initial value `const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(someInitialValue)` the value seen in `myValue` can be laggy. I'm not sure why, but it seems to be a common cause of problems with hooks.

If the component *always* renders multiple times (e.g something else is async) the problem does not appear because in the second render the variable will have the expected value.

To be sure you check localstorage on startup, you need an additional useEffect() which explicitly calls your function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setIsDark(getInitialIsDark());
}, [getInitialIsDark]); //dependency only needed to satisfy linter, essentially runs on mount.
```

Although most `useEffect` examples use an anonymous function, you might find more understandable to use named functions (following the clean-code principle of using function names for documentation)

```js
useEffect(function checkOnMount() {
  setIsDark(getInitialIsDark());
}, [getInitialIsDark]);   

useEffect(function persistOnChange() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && isReady) {
    console.log("save is dark " + isDark)
    window.localStorage.setItem("theming:isDark", isDark.toString())
  }
}, [isDark])
```

Comment: If I use this as described, I need to introduce another state or ref to make sure the persisitOnChange part is not called with the initial static value. Which ultimately results more or less in my second Solution - Which indeed works, but causes the UI to flicker. Maybe there is no way to implement this without the flickering. I have found multiple blog articles that useState(() => ...). Seems they are all wrong.

Comment: It's not about state, it's about separating events into separate `useEffect()` calls. WRT flickering, the best option might be to call `getInitialIsDark()` in App and pass the result in as a prop.

Comment: Note that persistOnChange is going to run regardless of how many other useEffect there are. You just need to work out the logic inside the function, or conversely why do you care if localstorage is updated with the same value?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where some styles weren't taking effect because they were being applied to through classes which were set on mount (like you only on production build, everything worked fine in develop).

I ended up switching the hydrate function React was using from `ReactDOM.hydrate` to `ReactDOM.render` and the issue disappeared.

```
// gatsby-browser.js
export const replaceHydrateFunction = () => (element, container, callback) => {
  ReactDOM.render(element, container, callback);
};
```

Comment: This was very helpful in solving my issue as well. I had a site that included a component code-split (use X component for mobile, and Y component for desktop). SSR defaulted to using the mobile component, since the window viewport isn't known at SSR time. The standard ReactDOM.hydrate method silently but visually failed during a desktop re-hydration since the mobile HTML was present the desktop HTML was expected. This answer solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me, try this and let me know if it works out.

#### First

In **src/components/** i've created a component **navigation.js**

```js
    export default class Navigation extends Component {
      static contextType = ThemeContext // eslint-disable-line
      render() {
        const theme = this.context  
        return (
          <nav className={'nav scroll' : 'nav'}>
            <div className="nav-container">
               <button
                 className="dark-switcher"
                 onClick={theme.toggleDark}
                 title="Toggle Dark Mode"
                >
              </button>
            </div>
          </nav>
        )
      }
    }
```

#### Second

Created a **gatsby-browser.js**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { ThemeProvider } from './src/context/ThemeContext'

    export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => <ThemeProvider>{element}</ThemeProvider>
```

#### Third

I've created a **ThemeContext.js** file in src/context/

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    const defaultState = {
      dark: false,
      notFound: false,
      toggleDark: () => {},
    }

    const ThemeContext = React.createContext(defaultState)

    class ThemeProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        dark: false,
        notFound: false,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const lsDark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark'))

        if (lsDark) {
          this.setState({ dark: lsDark })
        }
      }

      componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
        const { dark } = this.state

        if (prevState.dark !== dark) {
          localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(dark))
        }
      }

      toggleDark = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ dark: !prevState.dark }))
      }

      setNotFound = () => {
        this.setState({ notFound: true })
      }

      setFound = () => {
        this.setState({ notFound: false })
      }

      render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        const { dark, notFound } = this.state

        return (
          <ThemeContext.Provider
            value={{
              dark,
              notFound,
              setFound: this.setFound,
              setNotFound: this.setNotFound,
              toggleDark: this.toggleDark,
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
        )
      }
    }

    export default ThemeContext

    export { ThemeProvider }
```

This should work for you here is the reference I followed from the [official Gatsby site](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/)